# URL rewrite via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've to change this url : `http://localhost:8888/finance/schedule/?location=new_york`
to `http://localhost:8888/finance/schedule/location/new_york`
It's a wordpress site, my htaccess code is :

```
RewriteRule ^schedule/location/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\$ schedule/?location=$1
```

But nothing seems to happen, please suggest.

The whole htaccess file code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /finance/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /finance/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^schedule/location/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\$ schedule/?location=$1

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is `/finance/schedule/?location=new_york` a WP URL?

Comment: Yes its a WP URL but it is from the custom plugin

Answer (score 0):

This line is stopping it from ever reaching your later rule:

```
RewriteRule . /finance/index.php [L]
```

The `[L]` means "last," as in "this is the last rule to run if it matches."

And `\$` looks for a literal `$`, not the end of the string.

You also have two many matching groups in your rule.

You need something like this, instead (totally untested):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /finance/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^schedule/location/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+?)/?$ /wp-content/themes/financeinstitute/page_schedule.php/?location=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /finance/index.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank for your correction, I copy pasted the exactly same as your answer, but nothing seems to happen :(

Comment: I'll have to look at it later. One question: Where are you trying to direct this? That is, is there a file at `/finance/schedule`? If so, is it `/finance/schedule/index.php` or `/finance/schedule.php` (or something else)?

Comment: It's a wordpress site, and the custom plugin is being used. I am not sure about the file structure. I am just trying to make url look better.

Comment: Do you mean, "I am **not** sure about the file structure?" That is critical to URL rewriting.

Comment: Well schedule is a file, located in WP theme folder. it's file name is `page_schedule.php`

Comment: Okay, then I need to know the path to that file. Something like `/wp-content/themes/something/page_schedule.php`. Without that information, there's no way to make this work.

Comment: The path is `/wp-content/themes/financeinstitute/page_schedule.php`

Comment: In that case, you can try the edited answer above. This may not work, however; it sounds like you may have a hybrid theme/extension, and it may not like the way you are rewriting the URL.

Comment: The edited answer didn't work. Is there any more possibilities.

Comment: Please define "didn't work." It's still somewhat hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: using your answer in htacess, this url `http://localhost:8888/finance/schedule/location/new_york` says `Page Not Available`. I wanted to work that url as this url `http://localhost:8888/finance/schedule/?location=new_york`

Comment: It's still not clear what the second URL even means. There's no file at `http://localhost:8888/finance/schedule`, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57938/discussion-between-prakash-and-ed-cottrell).